# R Studio - Cannot use BASH in R Markdown

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I am learning R and R Markdown, working in R Studio.
I am running Windows 10 (64-bit), with Windows Subsystem For Linux activated. I checked that it works - I have installed Ubuntu and used BASH etc. and it works fine.

However, **when I try to use BASH** (or SH for that matter) inside R Markdown by writing:

````
```{bash}

pwd

```
````

It does not work when I try to 'knit' it, with the following **error**:

> 'Error in system2(cmd, code, stdout= TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env =
> options$engine.env) : "bash" not found Calls:  ... tryCatch
> -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->  Execution halted'

To my eyes, this error is saying that R/R Studio does not recognise I have BASH installed in my system.
However, when I open Ubuntu and do:

```
which bash
```

I get the expected result:

> /bin/bash

Does anyone have any idea why this happens, or how to fix this? Searching google has yielded nothing, and it's really frustrating me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237385/discussion-on-question-by-cybergeneticist-r-studio-cannot-use-bash-in-r-markdo).

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal Rmarkdown file, run on a Windows 10 machine with WSL2 installed, renders correctly with `rmarkdown::render("filename.rmd")` and generates a HTML file:

````
test rmd

```{bash}
pwd
```

```{r}
print("hello world")
```
````

Note that the current directory is in the *Windows* filesystem (`c:\...`), but translated into the Linux filesystem as used by WSL (`/mnt/c/...`).

[image]

Comment: Trying your minimal example, substituting my correct path in the `rmarkdown::render("filename.rmd")` step, it produces the same error as described above.
See the link to a screenshot if this helps:https://imgur.com/a/5aJTLBX

Comment: Judging from your other question, you're running the 32-bit version of R. Switch to the 64-bit version

Comment: Or, since you say that it works on another machine, there is something wrong with this machine. Reinstall R and Rstudio

Comment: Your comment about R 32 vs 64 bit is probably on point here. Upon checking `R.Version()` it appears it is using the i386 - the 32-bit R, despite both 32 and 64 being installed. I am now looking how to prevent R from installing the 32 bit as well as 64 bit, and will post back with results.

Comment: Honestly you should be able to just reinstall with all the defaults. Don't change anything, and it should work out of the box

Comment: Reinstalling R and unchecking 32-bit installation, so only 64-bit gets installed worked!
Now both BASH and Python work out of the box. Thanks

Edit: As a side note, I will say here I have afterwards found how to change which R version - 32 or 64 bit R Studio uses: go to **Tools -> Global Options -> General -> R Version**